# Display image in system configuration in magento?

Tags: magento, configuration, magento-1.7, system.xml

I want to display a image for radio button value in system configuration.

As well i want to show that selected image in my front-end.

Help me to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific and offer an example you've tried? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you need select image in back-end in system.xml:

```
<config>
   <sections>          
      <section_name>
         <groups>
            <group_name>
                <fields>
                   <logoimage translate="label comment">
                       <label>Logo</label>
                       <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                       <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
                       <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">theme</upload_dir>
                       <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">theme</base_url>
                       <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                   </logoimage>
                 </fields>
             </group_name>
         </groups>
     </section_name>
   </sections>
</config>
```

and then paste in front-end:

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . Mage::getStoreConfig('section_name/group_name/logoimage'); ?>
```

Comment: i don't want to get the image form the system(upload option). Need to display image form my system.